# Search filter by data

Tags: jquery, search, filter, selector

I try to filter data by using jQuery/HTML selector like

```
$("li[data-filter*='keyword']")
```

But this cannot filter and get same result **"keyword1 keyword2"** and **"keyword2 keyword1"** , Do you understand ?

I will give you demo..

**HTML :**

```
<input>

<li data-filter="apple pie gummi bears gummi bears john">
    Apple pie gummi bears gummi bears John
</li>

<li data-filter="oat cake chocolate bar chupa chups dessert tootsie">
    Oat cake chocolate bar chupa chups dessert tootsie
</li>
<li data-filter="jujubes cookie sugar plum lemon drops candy">
    Jujubes cookie sugar plum lemon drops candy
</li>
```

**jQuery :**

```
var filter_timer;
$("input").keypress(function() {
    clearTimeout(filter_timer);
    filter_timer=setTimeout(function(){
        filter();
    },500);
});

function filter() {

var keyword = $("input").val();

if($("li[data-filter*='"+keyword+"']").length) {
    $("li").animate({opacity:0.4}).css({"text-decoration":"line-through"});
    $("li[data-filter*='"+keyword+"']").animate({opacity:1}).css({"text-decoration":"blink"});
}else{
    $("li").animate({opacity:1},function(){$("li").removeAttr("style")});}
}
```

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/9eaXD/

How can I get same result when I searching **apple pie** and **pie apple** or **apple gummi pei**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do can't be accomplished with attribute selectors. `[data-filter*="apple pie"]` matches only elements whose `data-filter` attribute contains *exactly* the string `apple pie`.

You should use `.filter()` instead:

```
$("input").keypress(function() {
    var keywords = $(this).val().split(' ');

    $('li').removeClass('matched');
    $("li[data-filter]").filter(function() {
        var filters = $(this).data('filter').split(' ');

        for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            var keyword = keywords[i];

            if (filters.indexOf(keyword) == -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }).addClass('matched');
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9eaXD/8/**

You could optimize this a little more by creating the `filters` array for each element on page load:

```
$("li[data-filter]").filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.data('filter', $this.data('filter').split(' '));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for `filter()` but your code has a little problem when seaching `apple` (one keyword) so cannot show any result. But when search `apple ` (with space) i come result

Comment: @l2aelba: That's because it's only running on `keypress`. Change it to `keyup` and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9eaXD/9/